# May one engage in pleasurable voluntary activities during the Three Weeks?

Tags: three-weeks, hanaah-benefit

During the Three Weeks (or at least during the Nine Days), is there a recommendation to distance oneself from voluntary activities that one particularly enjoys?

(The question is less regarding commandments, and more regarding voluntary activities. For example, perhaps the permission to learn Torah during these weeks is due to the *commandment* to learn, with less consideration of the possibility that one may enjoy performing that commandment.)

related: [Learning music theory during the Three Weeks?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/105669/learning-music-theory-during-the-three-weeks/105963#105963)

Comment: משנכנס אב ממעטים בשמחה

Comment: THat is exactly the case when we say that we don't have the authority (and need) to add additional restrictions to what the Rabbis already ruled. THere's a Gemmorah that after the destruction of the 2nd Temple people thought to extend the 9th of Av restrictions to every day, but it wasn't accepted Halachicly.

Comment: @DoubleAA That's exactly the point. We reduce the negative influence of Av through permissible simchah. The over-riding general rule of 'Serve HaShem with joy.' isn't abrogated during the 3 weeks. On the contrary, it becomes even more important.

Comment: @Yaacov no that's exactly not what it means.

Comment: R Mike Feuer: we do less work (ממעטים) joyously (בשמחה). But would the "less work" be that of voluntary activities, to make for time for mitzvot?

Comment: source: https://soundcloud.com/ravaaron/finding-comfort-in-the-breaking?in=ravaaron/sets/the-the-weeks-5776

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rav Gormon of Chabad Toronto: recommended to me that until the Hodesh She'hal Bo (ashkenazim) or Shavua She'hal Bo (sepharadim) it is permissible, min ha'din. From that point onward, it would be recommended otherwise, from the mishna's point of משנכנס אב ממעטים בשמחה.